# Java not getting the right condition

Tags: java, android, object

I trying to get info in database and sending for an object called Question.

When i got null in database and send it to the field of the object.. I suppose that field will be "null", cause the field is an String.

But i tried all ways to verify it and i cant...

I tried:

```
    Question a = new Question();
    a.setAnswer(database.getAnswer(id));
    // Way 1
    if(a.getAnswer() == null) {
            Log.d("Way 1", "successfully");
    } 
    // Way 2
    if(a.getAnswer() == "null") {
            Log.d("Way 2", "successfully");
    }
    //Way 3
    if(a.getAnswer().equals(null)) {
            Log.d("Way 3", "successfully");
    }
    // Way 4
    if(a.getAnswer().equals("")) { 
            Log.d("Way 4", "successfully");
    }
```

But I didn't got result...

I put in log to log my Question.getAnswer() too:

And here's the result:

```
    D/Here == >: null
```

Comment: You are not comparing strings correctly in Way 2, use `equals` as you did in Way 4.

Comment: it is "Java", not "JAVA"

Answer (score 0):

In Way 2

use : `if(a.getAnswer().equals("null")( {`

This is the way two strings must be compared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for comparison

```
if(a.getAnswer().equals("")) {
    Log.d("Way 1", "successfully");
}
```

This will work as expected

Comment: Maybe getAnswer returns already a `String` object, so in that case, it is not necessary to do that.

Comment: however, Naveed cannot be sure as he cannot see the declarations. this will ensure that `getAnswer` is always a `String`.

Comment: @ylun you are right `getAnswer` will return string there is no need to convert string again to string.